# outlook mailbox SMTPDataError 550 delivery result banner

Tags: email, outlook, smtp

I was using smtp service of outlook mailbox in my web app. And it worked well in last several days. However a sudden error occured during a usual test:

```
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/smtplib.py", line 799, in sendmail
   raise SMTPDataError(code, resp)
smtplib.SMTPDataError: (550, b'5.3.4 554-554 5.2.0 STOREDRV.Deliver;delivery result banner')

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/threading.py", line 920, in _bootstrap_inner
  self.run()
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/threading.py", line 868, in run
  self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
File "/home/lancecopper/code/python/flasky/app/email.py", line 9, in send_async_email
  mail.send(msg)
File "/home/lancecopper/code/flasky/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/flask_mail.py", line 492, in send
  message.send(connection)
File "/home/lancecopper/code/flasky/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/flask_mail.py", line 152, in __exit__
  self.host.quit()
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/smtplib.py", line 867, in quit
  res = self.docmd("quit")
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/smtplib.py", line 403, in docmd
  self.putcmd(cmd, args)
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/smtplib.py", line 349, in putcmd
  self.send(str)
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/smtplib.py", line 341, in send
  raise SMTPServerDisconnected('please run connect() first')
smtplib.SMTPServerDisconnected: please run connect() first
```

I have little knowledge about underlining mechanism of smtp. Can anybody give me some clue about this kind of error.

By the way, I'm a poor guy living inside GFW(Great Firewall of China).Would it be possible that the error above was caused by interruption of GFW?

Answer (score 3):

I encountered this issues when using mutt to.

login your account and verify mobile phone number and check it again.
You may got message like on your phone:

[TLSG] Microsoft 访问代码:2130

Comment: True.
--------------
`Hello **name**,
We limit the number of recipients for an email message to help free the world from spammers. We're sorry that it's getting in your way.
What do you need to do?
To send your mail, please remove some recipients. You may be able to increase the limit by verifying your account.
Verifying your account helps you enjoy Outlook.com with fewer interruptions and limitations.
Thanks,
The Outlook.com Team`